# Error when run php in eclipse

Tags: php

I am trying to run php in eclipse, but I am getting the error below each time clicking on run.

> Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

> Error 404
>   localhost Fri Jul 27 21:32:48 2012 Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

I am still able to run php using browser. Also when i update the file URL manually in eclipse it will work properly for me and show correct output.

The current file directory (that show the above error): `http://localhost/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/LOCALHOST/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/php_video/source/example5.php`

When I edit it to be as the following it will work perfectly for me:  `http://localhost//php_video/source/example5.php`

I think I need to chaneg something in setting and configuration. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your "testing" site link is set up as `localhost/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/LOCALHOST/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/`when it should just be `localhost`

Comment: How i can change that. Please don't assume  i know everything in eclipse.

Comment: I have no idea - why not just test in your browser? Chrome has excellent developer tools built-in (F12).

Answer (score 0):

try using aptana studio 3.0. i went there and never switched back.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in your browser (chrome is best for the majority of your testing, then IE since everything tends to break in IE) rather than your IDE. PHP is interpreted, not compiled, so you don't need the IDE to compile & execute your files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but i still need to know how i can debugging and run php in eclipse

Comment: @user1558490 Just echo out the values of the variables you're inspecting. Then remove them. In 6 years I have never come across a PHP developer who uses the IDE to debug.

Comment: please let me know what you are using to write php and then run it? that may help me more

Comment: @user1558490 Write php in ANY text editor or IDE, then open your browser and navigate to your local server (http://localhost/). You may need a better understanding of how PHP works. http://www.ghacks.net/2009/01/08/web-development-how-does-php-work/

Comment: Appreciate you help... Thank you